# Updating the default img src in html, when the img src doesn't have a value

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an image tag with empty source and from my JS file, i will update the src of the img tag. When I update the source, if the image is not found, I want to display default image.

`<img src="" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.onload=null; this.src='images/logo/1.png';"/>`

With the above code, on loading the HTML page, it is showing the default image, since src is not set. I don't want it to be displayed on initial page load. I want to show the default image only after the image src is set and the set source is not found.

I tried the below code, but still no luck. Looks like, this.src is having the value of our index.html location.

`<img src="" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.onload=null; if (!this.src) this.src='images/logo/1.png';"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `display` property for the `img` as `none` by adding this attribute to the image tag `style="display:none;"` like so

`<img src="" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.onload=null; if (!this.src) this.src='images/logo/1.png';" style="display:none;"/>`

in the JS file, you can set the `display:block;` after you set the `src` attribute

Here is an example with a button(image shows up 3 seconds after pressing button)

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myImg");
elem.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150"; //set the source
function myFunction(){
  elem.style.display = "block"; //set the style of image to block
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.onload=null; if (!this.src) this.src='images/logo/1.png';" style="display:none;"/>

<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">Show Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. it change the `src` of `img` if it empty.

Here is an example

```html
<img src="" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.onload=null; if (!this.attributes.src.value) this.attributes.src.value='https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif';"/>
```